# Oracle database compactibility check

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, oracle19c, ojdbc

We are using oracle 19c enterprise edition DB. There are 2 application which connects to this db. One is running on java 8 and the other is running on java 11. Both are using ojdbc8.jar with 19.3.0.0 version.
Now I want to upgrade the application running on java 11 to java 17 without making any change in the first application (which is running on java 8). The application in which I want to upgrade to java 17 is a springboot gradle project. Is it possible to upgrade just the second application without affecting the forst application? If possible, then how?

Checked the oracle support page for version compactibilities. It was confusing

Answer (score 0):

The information that are you looking for is available on the download page.
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

For upgrading application from java 11 to java 17 you have to use ojdbc11.jar that implements jdbc4.3 specs, and in any case to use all the availability and protection feature from Enterprise edition you have to deal with UCP drivers.

Upgrading the application depends on the applications and how you deploy your code. So it is up to you to answer this question.
In general in one system you may have 2 different JDK.